# entitymetadawrapper with field collection multi value

Tags: entities

How can I save multiple values in a *multi-value field collection* using **EntityMetadataWrapper** ?

Here's some of my code

```
$field_collection = entity_create('field_collection_item', array('field_name' => 'MY_FIELD_COLLECTION'));
$field_collection->setHostEntity('commerce_line_item', $line_item);
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('field_collection_item', $field_collection);

for($delta=0; $delta<$max_delta; $delta++) {
  //MISSING something like $wrapper->setDelta($delta);
  $wrapper->field_example->set($new_value);  
  $wrapper->other_field_example->set($new_value); 
  $wrapper->save(); 

}

$field_collection->save();
```

I'm fighting with the field delta : I can't use `$wrapper->field_example[$delta]->set($new_value)` because the wrapper itself is the multi-value field, not its children fields.

So I need to find a way to perform something like

```
$wrapper[$delta]->field_example->set($new_value);
```

But this returns "*Fatal error: Cannot use object of type EntityDrupalWrapper as array*".

**Summary : where can I set the delta of the wrapper in the loop ?**

Comment: You can't (not with [`setHostEntity()`](http://api.drupalecommerce.org/api/misc/field_collection!field_collection.module/function/FieldCollectionItemEntity%3A%3AsetHostEntity/7.x), anyway). That function just adds to the existing data, it doesn't offer a way to set the delta. The simplest way would be to reproduce the parts of that function you need and set the delta manually in your own function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found this example in one of the [bug reports](https://www.drupal.org/node/1937866) on d.o, hopefully it will clear things up a bit:

```
// Load the entity and wrap it.
$entity = entity_load_single('my_entity', $entity_id);
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('my_entity', $entity);
// Create new field collection items.
$collections = array();
// This is a contrived example so assume $things contains some data that might be set on the collections.
foreach ($things as $thing) {
  $fc = entity_create('field_collection_item', array('field_name' => 'field_example_collections'));
  $fc->setHostEntity('my_entity', $entity, $entity->language, FALSE);
  // Skip saving the host entity since the order in which we are creating the items is not the order we want them saved.
  $fc->save(TRUE);
  $collections[] = $fc;
}
// Set the field collection items via the wrapper.
$wrapper->field_example_collections->set($collections);
// Save the entity.
$wrapper->save();
```

Just as @Clive commented, you need to first load the host entity that this field collection field is attached to (I'm assuming it's a `commerce_line_item`?), then loop through your data and create field collection entities. Then after you've done assigning values, collect them all in an array and set the array as the new value for the host entity's field collection field.

Comment: That's a good way to do it - you can control the delta by setting the order of `$things` to something appropriate, it'll have the same effect. I _think_ you probably want to change it to `$fc->setHostEntity('my_entity', $entity, LANGUAGE_NONE, FALSE);`, just to save duplicated effort to create the 'link'. It's minimal though

Comment: Powerful code example! Just a point : I had to change `$entity->save()` to `$wrapper->save()`. Seems to be all right now. Tks again !

Comment: Last, I was wondering what @Clive meant by change to `$fc->setHostEntity('my_entity', $entity, LANGUAGE_NONE, FALSE);`, just to save duplicated effort to create the 'link'?

Comment: @Kojo It's minor, it just stops `setHostEntity` from adding the link to the field collection onto the host node explicitly, since you're adding it yourself with `$wrapper->field_example_collections->set($collections);`. Micro-optimising probably

Answer (score 1):

To save multi-value field, you need to wrap the values in `array()`, e.g.

```
$wrapper->field_example->set(array($new_value1, $new_value2, $new_value3));
```

or append as this would be an array:

```
$wrapper->field_example[] = $next_value;
```

Here is some more complete example:

```
try {
  $line_item = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_line_item', $entity);
  // Create the collection entity, set field values and set it's "host".
  $field_collection_item = entity_create('field_collection_item', array('field_name' => 'MY_FIELD_COLLECTION'));
  $field_collection_item->setHostEntity('commerce_line_item', $line_item->value());
  $collections[$pname] = entity_metadata_wrapper('field_collection_item', $field_collection_item);
  $collections[$pname]->field_example = array($new_value1, $new_value2);
  $collections[$pname]->other_field_example[] = $new_value;
  $collections[$pname]->other_field_example[] = $other_value;
  $line_item->save();
} catch (Exception $e) {
  drupal_set_message(t('Error message: @error.',
        array('@error' => $e->getMessage())), 'error');
  watchdog_exception('MYMODULE', $e);
}
```